# Is the point promised by Borsuk-Ulam stable under perturbation of the map?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, dynamical-systems

The Borsuk-Ulam theorem says that, given a continuous map $f: S^n \to \Bbb R^n$, there is some point $x \in S^n$ with $f(x)=f(-x)$. There may, of course, be many such points (maybe $f$ is constant!) But I'd still like to show that some "equivariant" point is stable in the following sense.

We start with a map $\varphi: X \times S^n \to \Bbb R^n$, $X$ some compact manifold. We think of this as a *continuously varying family* of maps $\varphi_x: S^n \to \Bbb R^n$, given by $\varphi_x(p) = \varphi(x,p)$. The Borsuk-Ulam theorem guarantees there is some point $p_x$ with $\varphi_x(p_x) = \varphi_x(-p_x)$.

What I'd like to know is: is there always a continuous function $\psi: X \to S^n$, such that $\varphi_x(\psi(x)) = \varphi_x(-\psi(x))$? (This should be called stability of the equivariant point because given a map $\varphi_x$, under a mild perturbation of $\varphi_x$, we may still find two equivariant points that are close to one another.) Said another way, **given a continuous family of maps $S^n \to \Bbb R^n$, can I continuously choose an equivariant point?**

It would be good to prove this at first for $X = I$. If one can do that, and prove a relative version of the theorem for $D^n$ relative its boundary (including $n=1$), one can prove it for all finite CW-complexes. I tend to think that it will be true provided it's true for $X = I$. But I can't seem to make any progress on this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated, the answer is no. Consider the case of $n=1$ so that maps $f: S^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ are simply maps $f: [0, 2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for which $f(0) = f(2\pi)$, and the Borsuk-Ulam theorem states for every such continuous map $f$ there exists $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$ such that $f(\theta) = f(\theta+\pi)$.

Let $X = [0,1]$ and consider $\varphi: [0,1] \times [0, 2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$\varphi(t,\theta) = t(1-t) \phi(\theta),$$
where $\phi: [0, 2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is supported in $[0, \pi]$ and defined on its support by
$$\phi(\theta) = |\theta-\pi/2|-\pi/2 \text{ (for }0 \le \theta \le \pi).$$
The graph of $\phi$ is given by

[image: graph of \phi]

Notice that $\varphi : [0,1] \times [0, 2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and in fact defines a homotopy from the constant $0$ function to itself. Moreover, 
$$\{ (t, \theta) \in [0,1] \times [0,2\pi] : \varphi(t,\theta) = \varphi(t,\theta + \pi) \} =\big(\{0,1\}\times[0, 2\pi]\big) \cup\big([0,1] \times \{0, \pi, 2\pi\}\big).$$
Now, of course, we can continuously choose an equivariant point for $\varphi$. Namely, take $\psi :[0,1] \rightarrow [0,2\pi]$ to be the constant $0$ (or $\pi$ or $2\pi$) function.

However, consider what happens if we translate $\phi$ in $\theta$ and concatenate the resulting homotopy $\hat{\varphi}$ with the homotopy $\varphi$ above. Explicitly, consider $\Phi : [0,1] \times [0, 2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$\Phi(t,\theta) = \varphi(2t, \theta), \text{ if }0 \le t \le 1/2 \text{, and}  $$
$$\Phi(t,\theta) = \varphi(2t-1, \theta-\pi/2), \text{ if }1/2 \le t \le 1.$$
Now, the equivariant points for this family are
$$\{ (t, \theta) \in [0,1] \times [0,2\pi] : \Phi(t,\theta) = \Phi(t,\theta + \pi) \} =\big(\{0,1/2,1\}\times[0, 2\pi]\big) \cup\big([0,1/2] \times \{0, \pi, 2\pi\}\big) \cup \big( [1/2,1] \times\{\pi/2, 3\pi/2\}\big), \text{ which is pictured as}$$
[image: equivariant points]

It follows that there does not exist any function $\Psi :[0,1] \rightarrow [0,2\pi]$ such that $\Psi(t)$ is an equivariant point for all $t$ and $\Psi$ is continuous at $t=1/2$.

I'll additionally remark that, while this example shows that it's impossible to continuously choose equivariant points in a neighborhood of $t=1/2 \in [0,1]$, it is still possible to continuously choose equivariant points in a "one-sided neighborhood" of $t=1/2$. I expect, however, that even this is impossible in general and that a counter-example might be obtained by concatenating infinitely many $\Phi(t, \theta)$ which are suitably rescaled.

Comment: This is great, thanks. I agree that it's probably possible to break the one-sided neighborhood business. Do you expect that the question will still be false if I demand in addition smoothness (of $X$ and of $\varphi: X \times S^n \to \Bbb R^n$)?

Comment: @MikeMiller Wouldn't it be possible to use some sort of implicit function theorem in this case (when smoothess is added) ? // Just curious.

Comment: @Evgeny: I think something like that should work, though I need to write down the details.

Comment: I don't think an implicit function theorem argument will work in general unless there are additional assumptions on the derivative of $\varphi$ at the equivariant points. Indeed, I think the above counterexample can be modified to be $C^\infty$ by replacing $\phi$ and $t(1-t)$ with suitable smooth bump functions which have the same support as $\phi$ and $t(1-t)$, respectively, and are positive on the interior of their supports.